# adding a 0 before a two digit number in an array full of three digit numbers subtracts 2? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I created an array that has 120, 200, and 016 and when i print the array, the 016 appears as 14. Why is this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] x = {120, 200, 016};
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        System.out.print (x[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Leading zero causes the number to be interpreted as octal in java

Comment: Would you like to cast the number to String? I think then it is possible

Comment: Why do coders confuse Halloween and Christmas? Because Oct 31 = Dec 25.

Answer (score 1):

Java treats an integer with a leading `0` as a number with radix `8` (instead of using radix `10` as is the case for decimal numbers). The following demo will help you understand this concept in a clear way:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt("16", 8);
        System.out.println(x);
        int y = 016;
        System.out.println(y);
        System.out.println(x == y);
        int z = 16;
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(y == z);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
14
14
true
16
false
```